# Notification not received in iOS after I transfer bundle id from apple developer account to another

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, apple-push-notifications, message

I use APNs Authentication key to configuration in my firebase.
I do transfer app bundle from developer account to another account.
After transfer, my app in iOS device cannot received notification from firebase.

Is it mean that, my old APNS authentication key is not working? Am I need to create APNs key in my new developer account?

If like that, my existing user that already install my app will not received notification, until I upload new app version?

Answer (score 0):

you must add a new project in firebase, because of the new apple developer account and new bundle Identifier, and download new
"GoogleService-Info.plist" file and replace it.
after that, you must define new APNS authentication and add the key to firebase with the new bundle id.

your "Team Id" now changed and you must add or edit your firebase project. check the below pic in last item (this pic is in firebase project settings):

[image]

Comment: I just only transfer the existing bundle Identifier from one account to another, not create new bundle. 
The problem is in existing bundle identify app not received notification.

Comment: In this example, ABCDE12345 is the Team ID and com.cocoacasts.scribbles is the bundle ID search string. The Team ID and the bundle ID search string are separated by a period.

ABCDE12345.com.cocoacasts.scribbles

Comment: Base on your pic, you mean that I need to replace old Team ID to new Team ID?
Not replace APNs key from old to new APNs key?
If just replace Team ID in old configuration, I Done it, but still not working.

Comment: Your apns key must create with new teamID, old apns key has created with old teamID

Comment: In firebase setting, I already replace old APNs key to new APNs key that created with new teamID, but my old app still cannot received notification.

Comment: if you want to keep the old app you must create a new project in Firebase.
your analytics push notification and Crashlytics too. you didn't say that you want to keep your old app.
when you change your account and publish your app to another account, originally you created a new Application, Firebase can't figure out.

Comment: when you have 2 account, your backend must call push API for both project.

Answer (score 0):

Keys and certificates are generated per team. If you're using your personal team to publish the app, you need to generate all new certificates and keys after you changes your developer account.

On your backend you should somehow solve the problem of using both keys during transition period: An old one for your old app versions and the new one for the new app, published from another account. Otherwise users who use older app versions won't be receiving your push notifications.

**In case of Firebase**

In Firebase console you need to create a new app, using new Team ID. In your Apple Developer account you need to create new APNs key and add it to your new app in Firebase. On your backend you need to handle these two applications separately, because they'll have different Firebase keys.

Comment: Sorry I am not yet understand about your answer, could you pls explain it in detail again?

Comment: In firebase, I still use old Push Key of old apple account and it not received notification. So it mean I need to create new Push key from new account??

Comment: I updated my answer with more information about Firebase: New app should be added to the project, using the new Team ID and the rest of data. A new APNs key should be added there.

Comment: I have only 1 app bundle id, after I transfer it from old developer account to another developer account, it still the old bundle id, it is not new bundle id. What you mean that create new app in firebase?? Create new app in firebase, it will need new app bundle id.

Comment: See @maziar-saadatfar answer–it partly describes my idea using a nice screenshot. If you don't care about your old app version, you can update your Firebase app data with new one. If you do care, you should create the second one and support both by your backend that send push notifications.

Comment: For the new build app, I think it will be OK. 
But I really care about my old app now it not received notification with my old Push key configuration. You said, i need to create new app in firebase, new app it mean new bundle id. So how can it push to my old app??